# dropping unit arrows from free SMCCs?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there anything known about what happens when you create the free almost-SMCC from a set of objects (following perhaps the construction of Troelstra 1992:81-86, but leave out the unit axiom arrows ($\lambda_A:1*A\rightarrow A$)?  I can't seem to find anything out about such things in the literature.

The motivation is that there is an activity in linguistics called `glue semantics' in which you use 'rudimentary' linear logic a.k.a. free SMCCs to model assembly of word meanings, but the unit and unitors aren't used in it at all, and there is a bit of an issue in handling the meanings of the actual words, which such a category might help with.

Further Remarks based on the useful comments below: for the linguistic application, it might even be good to have arrows such as $1\rightarrow[A,A]$ and the one discussed in the Houston et al. paper below be missing, because in meaning assembly we want to go from postulates representing word meanings to an assembled meaning for the whole.  E.g. Walk$\otimes$John$\rightarrow$Walk(John) where Walk is of type $[E,P]$ and John is of type $E$, and we don't want the conclusion to be filled up with contentless extra junk such as $[A,A]$ for arbitrary $A$.

This problem is currently avoided by stating the type that you want the assembled meaning to have, typically `proposition', but this is oversimplistic, and it would be nice to have an assembly scheme that would list the finite number of sensible assemblies with no unwanted junk.  Basically, a logic where the only thing that follows from nothing is nothing.  So the 'naive solution' is perhaps not the wrong one here.

Comment: So you also don't want objects to have identity maps? The transpose of $\lambda$, the canonical map $1\to [A,A]$, would have to disappear too.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for literature on **semi-monoidal** categories? A quick google search gives https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504037 which is about linear logic without units.

Comment: Thanks!  That might be it!  Houston has a slightly earlier thesis on the subject, too.

Comment: Sorry, what is SMCC?

Comment: symmetric monoidal closed category, explained in ch 16 of Barr&Wells 1999, for example.  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf is an accessible account of what they're good for and how they relate to other things.

Comment: It may be the case that for the linguistic application (composition of word meanings), a category missing $1\rightarrow[p,p]$ would be adequate; the idea is that the source of the arrow is a tensor of word-meanings, the target the result, and the arrows that disappear when the unitors are removed don't seem to be helpful here, even if the resulting system seem mathematically defective (no internal hom).  For linguistics, we want the simplest kind of system that gets the job done, no matter how lame it seems.